# method finalize and exceptions

Tags: java, exception, finalize

I don't understand very well when an exception is ignored by the GC when it reclaims from the memory an object.

If I have a `try/catch` into a finalize method I see it is always executed... so which are the cases where the exception is not thrown?

Thanks.

Comment: Some example code would be helpful along with this question...

Comment: Exceptions which are ignored are the ones which are thrown *out* of method finalize(). If you have the try/catch inside that method, then the exception won't go out of the method, and the GC simply won't see that.

Answer (score 4):

the `finalize` method is run by the finalizer thread. if you throw exception, the finalizer will ignore it (swallow it). Otherwise, the finalizer thread would die.
This applies to exceptions that are thrown and not caught by your code (inside `finalize()`). If you catch the exception, it is business as usual.

Answer (score 3):

The two existing answers appear to say that the finalizer will ignore any uncaught exceptions. This appears to contradict the answer here: [Exception in finalize method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11233605/exception-in-finalize-method) which appears to have a correct reference to the JSL. It says that uncaught exceptions will abort the finalization of the object concerned (possibly leaking resources) but that the finalizer thread itself will continue finalizing other objects. This matches empirical results.

Comment: How is that different then saying that *uncought* (in the finalizer method) exception is ignored?

Comment: @OpDeCirkel because the uncaught exception is not ignored; rather it aborts the finalisation of the object concerned. If an exception thrown in a finaliser was ignored, it would complete the finalisation of that object (and free it) before continuing to finalise other objects.

Comment: Freeing the object itself is not part of the finalization of the object. Freeing of the object memory will happen whether or not `finalize()` throws an exception. The finalization of the object is to give the object the chance to free resources that might not otherwise be freed by the garbage collector (files, server connections, etc.). Also note that different objects may be finalized on different threads, possibly running concurrently. There is no "the" finalizer thread.

Answer (score 2):

It means that any exception thrown from the `finalize` method is ignored. However, exceptions inside it still work as usual.