# Triggering a user-visible exception in a finalize method

Tags: java, finalizer, autocloseable

*This question is the opposite of [Exception in finalize method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11233605/exception-in-finalize-method) and similar questions.*

I am creating an `AutoCloseable` class that poses serious risks if not properly closed.  I'm looking to fail-hard in such a case, so that users do not accidentally forget to do so.

I realize, and agree, that the general best practice is for `Closeable`s to fail gracefully and do their best to mitigate the caller's error, but in this case callers would not want to miss this.  If you disagree with the idea conceptually, I'll appreciate your feedback, but consider the question an academic exercise about Java internals in that case.

What I envision is raising an `IllegalStateException` and interrupting the user if my class's `finalize()` method is called, and the instance hasn't been cleaned up yet.  However `finalize()` explicitly swallows uncaught exceptions, making this tricky.  What is the best way to cause a `RuntimeException` that the user will see from the `finalize()` method?

Here's a demo class of what I've got so far:

```
public class SeriouslyCloseable implements AutoCloseable {
  // We construct an Exception when the class is initialized, so that the stack
  // trace informs where the class was created, rather than where it is finalized
  private final IllegalStateException leftUnclosed = new IllegalStateException(
      "SEVERE: "+getClass().getName()+" was not properly closed after use");
  private boolean safelyClosed = false;

  @Override
  public void close() {
    // do work
    safelyClosed = true;
  }

  @Override
  protected void finalize() throws IllegalStateException {
    if(!safelyClosed) {
      // This is suppressed by the GC
      throw leftUnclosed;
    }
  }
}
```

Note: I realize also that `finalize()` is not guaranteed to run, so anything I implement around this method is not absolutely going to happen.  I'd still like it to *probably* happen, if the GC gives us the chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t force throwing an exception from the `finalize` method as this method is executed by an arbitrary, implementation dependent `Thread` and it’s not clear in which `Thread` the exception should raise.

Even if you had an idea of which thread to aim at, there’s a good reason why `Thread.stop(Throwable)` is deprecated (and unsupported since Java 8): causing a thread to throw an arbitrary throwable at an arbitrary code location can cause a lot of harm. E.g. miss another `close()` operation which the thread was about to enter. Further, the thread making the mistake might not be alive any more at the time your `finalize` method is invoked.

---

In the end it’s not about throwing, but *reporting* an exception which you want to achieve. You can mimic the original, non-suppressing behavior like this:

```
@Override
protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
    if(!safelyClosed) {
        final Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
        t.getUncaughtExceptionHandler().uncaughtException(t, leftUnclosed);
    }
}
```

By default, it will print the exception stack trace to the console. The advantage over calling `printStackTrace` manually is that it works together with a possibly installed application specific exception handler:

```
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class ThrowableInFinalize {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(
                                          new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
      public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
        Logger.getLogger("ThrowableInFinalize")
              .log(Level.SEVERE, "uncaught exception", e);
      }
    });
    new ThrowableInFinalize();
    System.gc();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
  }

  private final IllegalStateException leftUnclosed = new IllegalStateException(
      "SEVERE: "+getClass().getName()+" was not properly closed after use");
  private boolean safelyClosed;
  @Override
  protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
    if(!safelyClosed) {
      final Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
      t.getUncaughtExceptionHandler().uncaughtException(t, leftUnclosed);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to simply terminate the JVM outright:

```
@Override
protected void finalize() throws IllegalStateException {
  if(!safelyClosed) {
    leftUnclosed.printStackTrace(System.err);
    System.exit(255);
  }
}
```

The following pretty consistently replicated the desired behavior, including showing a trace of where the unclosed `Closeable` was created:

```
private static void resourceLeak() {
  SeriouslyCloseable sc = new SeriouslyCloseable();
  //sc.close();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
  resourceLeak();
  System.gc();
  Thread.sleep(1000);
  System.out.println("Exiting Normally");
}
```

> ```
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: SEVERE: SeriouslyCloseable was not properly closed after use
>         at SeriouslyCloseable.<init>(SeriouslyCloseable.java:5)
>         at SeriouslyCloseable.method(SeriouslyCloseable.java:23)
>         at SeriouslyCloseable.main(SeriouslyCloseable.java:28)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Don't throw exception in finalize.

So how you can comunicate that serious programming error is present? You could log it. But that is usefull only when someone will read that log.

You could flip some flag that would make whole app unusable (or at least your library) - store that exception in static field (originally null) and in some operation throw it if it is set.
For it to survive JVM shutdown, you could write it into file (but sometimes you can't) and load it when starting and resume throwing it (until such file is deleted and application restarted).

You could shutdown JVM (as dimo414 suggested before me), but other applications on same app server will not thank you, and that would prevent closing other resources.

You could send some message somewhere else (eg. via http or JMS), but that would require somewhere else to be listening and less ignorable than logs.

And you could implement multiple options how to handle it and allow user to choose.